# ios / xcode Make Text Writing Direction Right to Left

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, right-to-left

Hi I'm trying to write a string in Xcode from right to left but can't find out how to do this.
The apple documentation says this shortcut works: ⌃⌥⌘⇠ but it doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the screen shot.......
[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer here might be what you're looking for?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6505055/812715

The basic idea is to add an invisible uni-code character that enables right to left text direction.

Here is a summary of what is said:
RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
Unicode : 202B UTF8 : E2 80 AB

To actually implement it:
uiTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u202B%@",textString];

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the most up to date version of Xcode, if not update and then try. If that is not helping find the date of the documentation. It is at the bottom of the page in the developer area.

Hope what helps!