# insert text at the end of Uitextview when typing?

Tags: keyboard, uitextview

I'm trying to develop a custom keyboard for arabic (right to left) sign language app

[image]

I'm trying for days to get text added at the end of the uitextview (the text should be incremented at the left of the current text),

It means that by default character is added at the current cusor position like in the image, I need it to be added on the left..

Any idea please?

NB: I tried to modify the solution listed here [Change the UITextView Text Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905500/change-the-uitextview-text-direction), this is exactly what I need but in "real time", I can't get it working for my custom keyboard.